# Looping through text and putting each line in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

so I have created a Shell command that is executed using PHP, and it returns something like this:

```
deathletsgo
lordhaigh
pampos
cheese510
TheLoneRanger6
```

And I've been trying to find a way to loop through and put each name in a different value in an array, so like `Servers[0]` would contain deathletsgo and `Servers[1]` would contain lordhaigh, etc, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "deathletsgo
lordhaigh
pampos
cheese510
TheLoneRanger6";
$servers = explode("\n", $string);
```

Comment: or, `$servers = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
`